# mouseenter event not working in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this code that doesn't seem to work in IE.  I have IE 11 to work with and I cannot get it to fire up.  All the other browsers are fine.  What am I doing wrong or is there are better approach for IE.

```
<select class="form-control" name="travail" data-title='Refresh for new     questions' size="10">
  <option>category</option>
  <option value="Description technique" data-id="72">soemthing else</option>
  <option value="Plan topographique" data-id="77">soemthing</option>
  <option value="Nivellement" data-id="78">some</option>
  <option value="Plan projet d'ensemble" data-id="76">thing</option>
  <option value="Méthode BOMA" data-id="77">else</option>
  <option value="Volumétrie" data-id="78">example</option>
</select>


$('select[name="travail"]').on('mouseenter', 'option', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
  //this is originally an ajax call, but it doesn't get fired in IE
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35nqv4nc/2/)

Comment: seems to work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/35nqv4nc/3/

Comment: I had made a mistake and have updated the code.  The goal is to get the data-id inside the select element from each option element.  Nothing I have tried will let me do this in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JS  to

```
$('select[name="travail"]').mouseenter(function(e) {
  console.log('over');
  //this is originally an ajax call, but it doesn't get fired in IE
});
```

I think it should work as I tested it.

The critical part is changing 
**obj.on('mouseenter'...)** to **obj.mouseenter(...)**